# webpack live hot reload for sass

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I am building a workflow for a react starter and would like to have my browser auto reload when I make a change to my scss files.

Currently, webpack will hot reload when I make a change in my index.js file (set as my entry point).  However when I change/add scss code in my scss file, it gets compiled, but the css doesn't get output anywhere and does not trigger a browser reload.

I am new to webpack would really appreciate some insight here.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/js/index.js', './src/scss/style.scss'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/index_bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].css',
                            outputPath: 'css/'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'extract-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'    
        })
    ]
}
```

My index.js entry point file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../components/App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('App')
);
```

And my App component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../../dist/css/style.css';



class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>         
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I've opened a more specific question about MiniCSS two days ago. This bounty also applies to that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318991/correct-use-of-minicssextractplugin-in-a-ssr-react-typescript-app/56324012#comment99265032_56324012

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually, `style-loader` is the one that is [responsible](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/blob/6134c6e3909c988cef06c36810e013fbd9064d7b/src/index.js#L42-L64) for CSS HMR.

You should add it at the end of the style pipeline, only for dev.
For production, you can remain your config.

It should look something like that:

```
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    devMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: 'css-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader'
    }
  ]
}
```

**Pay attention**, the best practice of extracting css into a separate file is to use [`MiniCssExtractPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) if you are using webpack 4, or [`ExtractTextWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin), if you are using webpack < 4.

Comment: i added this in however now when use my build command I am not getting a compiled.generated css file in my dist directory

Comment: In dev mode you will use style-loader, that means that your css will be inside is file. Only in production mode you will get an external css file

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. For some reason webpack-dev-server doesn't apply the stylesheet (import 'styles.css') when importing without (only tested without) using css modules...

Answer (score -2):

Try using [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/) instead of Webpack. I used to spend hours configuring Webpack to get things like hot reload working. With Parcel, most things just "work" without a configuration file. For example, I wanted to start using Pug templates. Parcel recognized the `.pug` extension and automatically downloaded the required NPM dependencies!

In your case, just include the SCSS file in your app like this: `import '../scss/style.scss'` (notice the path is to the `.scss` source file relative to index.js). Parcel will automatically do the "sensible" thing.

Here are some references to get started with Parcel + React + SASS:

- [Build a React web app with Parcel.js lightning fast](https://developerhandbook.com/parcel.js/build-a-react-web-app-with-parcel/)
- [Parcel SCSS documentation](https://parceljs.org/scss.html)

---

Notable advantages and disadvantages of Parcel vs WebPack:

- Parcel requires minimal configuration; often no configuration.
- Parcel usually builds much faster than WebPack.
- The WebPack dev server seems more stable. (The Parcel dev server needs to restarted once in a while and doesn't play nice with Dropbox. Apparently this should be fixed in version 2.0.)
- When (an uncommon) configuration is required, it might not be obvious how to do that in Parcel; at least in WebPack, all the configuration is in one place.
- Sometimes Parcel's automatic configuration does thing people don't expect, confusing them.

Comment: I agree on everything about Parcel. Unfortunately, the project I'm on was built with WebPack and keeping it is an absolute requirement. So I need to go through MiniCSS, as explained in my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318991/correct-use-of-minicssextractplugin-in-a-ssr-react-typescript-app/56324012#comment99265032_56324012